# Where is my Java application's logs?

Tags: java, tomcat, slf4j

I am logging issues at my application like that:

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Student.class);
...
logger.info(msg);
logger.debug(another_msg);
```

I use Java and Spring framework running on Apache Tomcat 6 and slf4j for logging. When I debug my application on Intellij IDEA I see two tabs: Server and Tomcat Log. That logs are seen at Server tab. Under tomcat folder there is no file that records that logs. However I want to see it at file end if I can I want to change the log level(debug, info etc.) to see the logs.

How can I do it?

Comment: Based on thee logger Factory you are using(j2SE or Log4j), create log config file to define log levels and log file naming/location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the log4j.properties file in your application.

In the log4j.properties you specify the path for the log file.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967202/storing-log-into-log-file-using-slf4j-log4j)

Comment: slf4j does not imply log4j, how did you deduce that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I guess I assumed he used log4j. Luckily it worked for him.

Answer (score 1):

sl4j is not complete logging implementation, it is a facade to which we can couple other frameworks like log4j, java.util.logging, commons etc. so identify your logging framework and check the corresponding doc for the configuration file.FOr log4j it will be log4j.properties